# Wordpress Template not affecting the working, keeps defaulting to the index.php template

Tags: customization, templates, dropdown

I thought this would be incredibly simple, but it has not. I have an index.php file that has my default template for my site. I then made a new file called magazine.php for a template file so that I could make a seperate display for my "magazine" page. I wrote at the top of the magazine.php :

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Magazine
*/
?>
```

Simple enough. Then i assigned my "magazine" page to the "magazine" template in the drop down list on the magazine page. I then go to the site to see it and to my utter shock and dismay it simply does not show up. It defaults back to the index.php file... Am i missing something? It should go to the assigned template correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. So the problem may be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: does your theme have a page.php? are you using any caching? is the 'magazine' page by any chance your posts page?